# counting blocks and histogram of text data

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following challenge. I need to count how many blocks of info are in the column and what the size of each block, using Excel 2013.

Example (data in columns A... actual size of the columns 40.000 entries)
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
7Z7Z
7Z7Z
7Z7Z
B4B4
B4B4
Z2Z2
7Z7Z
7Z7Z
7Z7Z
7Z7Z
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
B4B4
D8D8
7Z7Z
B4B4
B4B4

In this example we have
B4B4 has 4 blocks (1 size 12, 1 size 10, 2 size 2)
7Z7Z has 3 blocks (1 size 4, 1 size 3, 1 size 1)
D8D8 has 1 block size 1
Z2Z2 has 1 block size 1

If possible not using VBA, because I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: to clarify, when you say "block" you mean "cell", right? And you need to count the number of occurrences of the same string, grouped by the number of sequential occurrences in the "A" column?  If so, this would be very easy to do with VBA, but I have my doubts formula functions would be able to to this

Comment: yes...each code B4B4 or 7Z7z is a cell

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Here's some VBA code that will do what you want (if I understand correctly)

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1
    Dim allStrings() As String
    ReDim allStrings(0) 'array starts at 1, 0 will be null
    Dim datablocks() As Integer
    ReDim datablocks(0, 0)
    Dim uniqueflag As Boolean
    uniqueflag = True
    Dim blockcount As Integer
    blockcount = 1
    Dim Blocks As Integer
    Blocks = 1
    Dim strReport As String

    Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
    'get unique strings
        For y = 0 To UBound(allStrings)
            If Cells(x, 1).Value = allStrings(y) Then
                uniqueflag = False
            End If
        Next y
        If uniqueflag = True Then
        'add unique string to array
            ReDim Preserve allStrings(UBound(allStrings) + 1)
            allStrings(UBound(allStrings)) = Cells(x, 1).Value
        Else
            uniqueflag = True 'reset flag
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    ReDim datablocks(UBound(allStrings), 0)

    For z = 1 To x - 1

    If z > 1 And newblock = flase Then
        If Cells(z, 1).Value = Cells(z - 1, 1).Value Then
            'current cell is same value as the last
            blockcount = blockcount + 1
        Else
            For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)
            'new block starts, record previous
                 If Cells(z - 1, 1).Value = allStrings(w) Then 'determine which string the block
                    ReDim Preserve datablocks(UBound(allStrings), Blocks) 'expand array
                    datablocks(w, Blocks) = blockcount
                    Blocks = Blocks + 1
                End If
            Next w

            If z = x - 1 Then
                'last item is a block of 1
                For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)
                    If Cells(z, 1).Value = allStrings(w) Then  'determine which string the block
                        ReDim Preserve datablocks(UBound(allStrings), Blocks) 'expand array
                        datablocks(w, Blocks) = 1
                        Blocks = Blocks + 1
                    End If
                Next w
            End If
            blockcount = 1
        End If
    End If

    Next z




    Dim uniqueblocksizes() As Integer
    ReDim uniqueblocksizes(0)
    Dim sizeexists As Boolean
    sizeexists = False

    For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)

        For r = 1 To Blocks - 1
            If datablocks(w, r) <> 0 Then
                For q = 0 To UBound(uniqueblocksizes)
                If uniqueblocksizes(q) = datablocks(w, r) Then
                    sizeexists = True
                End If
                Next q
                If sizeexists = False Then
                    ReDim Preserve uniqueblocksizes(UBound(uniqueblocksizes) + 1)
                    uniqueblocksizes(UBound(uniqueblocksizes)) = datablocks(w, r)
                End If
                sizeexists = False
            End If
        Next r

    Next w

    Dim tally As Integer
    Dim summary() As String
    ReDim summary(UBound(allStrings))
    For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
        summary(w) = "'" & allStrings(w) & "' Has blocks ("
    Next w

    tally = 0
    For q = 1 To UBound(uniqueblocksizes) 'for occurences of blocks
        For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
            For r = 1 To Blocks - 1 'for blocks datablocks(w, r)
                If uniqueblocksizes(q) = datablocks(w, r) Then
                    tally = tally + 1
                End If
            Next r
            'MsgBox (tally & " sets of '" & allStrings(w) & "' size " & uniqueblocksizes(q))
            If tally <> 0 Then
                summary(w) = summary(w) & " " & tally & " of size " & uniqueblocksizes(q) & ", "
            End If
            tally = 0
        Next w
    Next q

    For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
        summary(w) = summary(w) & ")"
        summary(w) = Replace(summary(w), ", )", ")")
        MsgBox (summary(w))
    Next w





    End Sub
```

Edited to write to data to sheet 3

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1
    Dim allStrings() As String
    ReDim allStrings(0) 'array starts at 1, 0 will be null
    Dim datablocks() As Integer
    ReDim datablocks(0, 0)
    Dim uniqueflag As Boolean
    uniqueflag = True
    Dim blockcount As Integer
    blockcount = 1
    Dim Blocks As Integer
    Blocks = 1
    Dim strReport As String
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
    'get unique strings
        For y = 0 To UBound(allStrings)
            If Cells(x, 1).Value = allStrings(y) Then
                uniqueflag = False
            End If
        Next y
        If uniqueflag = True Then
        'add unique string to array
            ReDim Preserve allStrings(UBound(allStrings) + 1)
            allStrings(UBound(allStrings)) = Cells(x, 1).Value
        Else
            uniqueflag = True 'reset flag
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop

    ReDim datablocks(UBound(allStrings), 0)

    For z = 1 To x - 1

    If z > 1 And newblock = flase Then
        If Cells(z, 1).Value = Cells(z - 1, 1).Value Then
            'current cell is same value as the last
            blockcount = blockcount + 1
        Else
            For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)
            'new block starts, record previous
                 If Cells(z - 1, 1).Value = allStrings(w) Then 'determine which string the block
                    ReDim Preserve datablocks(UBound(allStrings), Blocks) 'expand array
                    datablocks(w, Blocks) = blockcount
                    Blocks = Blocks + 1
                End If
            Next w

            If z = x - 1 Then
                'last item is a block of 1
                For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)
                    If Cells(z, 1).Value = allStrings(w) Then  'determine which string the block
                        ReDim Preserve datablocks(UBound(allStrings), Blocks) 'expand array
                        datablocks(w, Blocks) = 1
                        Blocks = Blocks + 1
                    End If
                Next w
            End If
            blockcount = 1
        End If
    End If

    Next z




    Dim uniqueblocksizes() As Integer
    ReDim uniqueblocksizes(0)
    Dim sizeexists As Boolean
    sizeexists = False

    For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings)

        For r = 1 To Blocks - 1
            If datablocks(w, r) <> 0 Then
                For q = 0 To UBound(uniqueblocksizes)
                If uniqueblocksizes(q) = datablocks(w, r) Then
                    sizeexists = True
                End If
                Next q
                If sizeexists = False Then
                    ReDim Preserve uniqueblocksizes(UBound(uniqueblocksizes) + 1)
                    uniqueblocksizes(UBound(uniqueblocksizes)) = datablocks(w, r)
                End If
                sizeexists = False
            End If
        Next r

    Next w

    Dim tally As Integer
    'Dim summary() As String
    'ReDim summary(UBound(allStrings))
    'For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
        'summary(w) = "'" & allStrings(w) & "' Has blocks ("
   ' Next w


    Dim tablerows As Integer
    tablerows = 2
    tally = 0
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Block Value"
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Block Size"
    Sheets(3).Cells(1, 3).Value = "Occurences"
    For q = 1 To UBound(uniqueblocksizes) 'for occurences of blocks
        For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
            For r = 1 To Blocks - 1 'for blocks datablocks(w, r)
                If uniqueblocksizes(q) = datablocks(w, r) Then
                    tally = tally + 1
                End If
            Next r
            If tally <> 0 Then
                Sheets(3).Cells(tablerows, 1).Value = allStrings(w)
                Sheets(3).Cells(tablerows, 2).Value = uniqueblocksizes(q)
                Sheets(3).Cells(tablerows, 3).Value = tally
                tablerows = tablerows + 1
                'summary(w) = summary(w) & " " & tally & " of size " & uniqueblocksizes(q) & ", "
            End If
            tally = 0
        Next w
    Next q
    'reorder data


    'For w = 1 To UBound(allStrings) 'for strings
    '    summary(w) = summary(w) & ")"
    '    summary(w) = Replace(summary(w), ", )", ")")
    '    MsgBox (summary(w))
   'Next w





    End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, it works out as expected, but is there a way to get the info as a table and not as message??

Comment: see my edit.  I haven't bothered to group lines of the same string together because you can do that with auto filter anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a combination of Excel formulae and a pivot table to do it.

Set up a counter in column B which starts at one for each new block:-

```
IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)
```

Set up a label in column C which shows a "Yes" for the end of each block:-

```
=IF(A3=A2,"No","Yes")
```

[image]

Insert a pivot table which uses the "Data" column for row labels, the "Count" column for column labels, a count field for the Sigma field, and the "Label" column as a filter:-

[image]

The pivot table appears like this:-

[image]